# Striping divs with jQuery (changing rows)

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form with dynamic rows and fields. For example, i have structure like this:

```
visible div
visible div
hidden div
visible div
```

When using `div:nth-child(odd)` and `div:nth-child(even)`, it would look visible like this:

```
striped
unstriped
unstriped
```

as the 3rd div is not visible.

How can I use `jQuery` to make sure its striped based on visible elements, and not on invisible?

Comment: jQuery("div:visible:odd"), this will also work!

Comment: Only if he uses `visible`, odds are he might use `opacity:0` or similar, where a `class` is way more logical.

Answer (score 2):

Change your CSS Selector, your are selecting `div:nth-child(odd)`.

You can add a class to visible elements and select by `div.visible:nth-child(odd)` or vice versa add a class to the invisble elements and select like this `div:not(.invisible):nth-child(odd)`.